# how to add toolbar inside QTabWidget PyQt5/Pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qtabwidget

I am going to build a simple app using *QTabWidet*, I added tool bar inside it, but the problem is that when I add new tab, the toolbar show on that tab but when I go to the previous tab, the toolbar disappear. What is the problem kindly help me to solve this issue.
Code and Pictures given below.

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import*
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import*
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl,Qt

class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabs = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.open_newTab)
        action1 = QAction("tool1",self)
        action2 = QAction("tool2",self)
        action3 = QAction("tool3")
        self.toolbar = QToolBar("title")
        # v.addWidget(toolbar)
        self.toolbar.addAction(action1)
        # toolbar.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.toolbar.addAction(action2)
        self.toolbar.addAction(action3)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.add_new_tab()
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background:green;")

    def add_new_tab(self,widget=None,label="Blank"):
        w = QWidget()
        v = QVBoxLayout()
        v.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        v.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        v.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        w.setLayout(v)
        w.setStyleSheet("background:blue")
        i = self.tabs.addTab(w,label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def open_newTab(self,i):
        if i==-1:
            self.add_new_tab()
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = mainwindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the above both pictures toolbar is present.
But when I go to the previous tab the toolbar disappear as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Set a layout for the widget added to the tab, and add the toolbars to it.

Comment: here I'm passing webenginewidgets instead of Qwidget.

Comment: Well, next time specify that in the question. The concept doesn't change, by the way: you should still add a QWidget, then set a layout for it and add the toolbar *and* the QWebEngineView to that layout.

Comment: @musicamante I have done as you told but now I'm facing the above issue., would you like to help me .

Comment: You cannot have the same widget in multiple places at the same time. Create a new toolbar for each new tab.

Comment: @musicamante Sir, I want add toolbar one time and want to access from each widget, plz help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243971/discussion-between-jawad-hussain-shah-and-musicamante).

Comment: I have already answered, you can *not* have the same widget on multiple places. While you could try to move it whenever the index of the tab is changed, it would be pointless for your purpose, since that toolbar will most certainly be used for the web view navigation, and sharing the same toolbar and actions for different pages is not a valid approach.